# Javascript regex to detect if a string has two "@" chars?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to do a simple verification that a string contains only one email address.  I am guessing that the easiest way to do this is to look for duplicate "@" chars and reject if that is the case.  I have this code, and I tested the regex on regex101 and it worked perfectly.  But I'm getting nothing from this now that it's in the page:

```
function checkemail(input){
var validformat=/^.*@.*@+.*?/
var returnval=false
if (!validformat.test(input.value))
alert("Invalid email format. Please correct and submit again.")
else{ returnval=true
}
if (returnval==false) input.select()
return returnval
}
```

And I am calling this with:

```
<form action="storemessage.php" method="POST" onSubmit="return checkemail(this.recipemail)">
```

And the name of the field is "recipemail."  Stumped.  Hoping this is something simple that I've just not had enough coffee to see...

Comment: There is some error message in the console? Is it rejecting valid input or accepting invalid ones?

Comment: @Thouartamazing That's not going to cover [all of the allowed syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Syntax). Given the complexity of e-mail addresses, it's best to use a more robust implementation of e-mail regex checking that has been well-vetted (typically that someone else wrote), or to make your own regex so ridiculously permissive that it's hardly more than checking that someone just entered *something*.

Comment: Could you please link the regex101 test case that worked? Looks like that regex you have there should be `var invalidformat`, and you don't need to negate the match result…

Comment: Notice that there are valid email addresses which contain multiple `@` signs.

Comment: @ajp15243 yes, i agree.  i added it as a suggestion, available for people searching for something more precise than just checking for two @ symbols.

Comment: you can use /^[\w.+-_]+@[^.][\w.-]*\.[\w-]{2,63}$/iu to match email addresses, but it will not cover all the possible senarios.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comments.  But my question isn't about validating emails.  I know there are very complex issues with that.  I'm just validating that there aren't more than one emails.  Which I think should be okay by checking to see if there are more than 1 @ chars.  I think the person below caught the problem:  I was validating on true instead of false...  Will check that now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex `test` returns true if the string matches the format (in your case, if it contains @x2). So you want to change your if condition to act on true values, not false:

```
if (validformat.test(input.value)) {
    alert("Invalid email format. Please correct and submit again.");
}
```

And perhaps you should rename your regex to `invalidformat`.

Comment: Thank you!  This is exactly what I was doing wrong.  Dooh!

Answer (score 0):

Validating emails in JS is a very tedious task, there are hundreds of weird scenarios you could account for, but it's simply not feasible.
So you have to draw the line somewhere.
Try this regex:

```
/^\s*[\w\-\+_]+(\.[\w\-\+_]+)*\@[\w\-\+_]+\.[\w\-\+_]+(\.[\w\-\+_]+)*\s*$/
```